# excessive RAM usage on local apache server

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

EDIT : I manually set the `$key` of the `$array` , so it will not be key/array/anything reserved .

EDIT2 : Here is a better video : http://www.screenr.com/ZEss

Checkout this 10 sec video: http://screenr.com/Ctss .

I am testing a wordpress theme on localhost. This issue arose when i changed theme/foldername of my theme .

Some code ref :

```
<?php
 //this is an array with ~20 values in it.
$array = (get_option('foo'));

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}

?>
```

This code runs around 4 times in different files of the theme.

Everything was working fine when i was working with a different theme name/folder name .
I am new to php , so please help me with this issue .

Comment: What are you trying to do? And why are you using a variable variable?

Comment: @Alexcp Say 'logo' is the key for a value then i can access its value by using $logo variable .

Comment: Why don't you just use $array['key'] instead

Comment: @Alexcp Actually(later) i figured out a different way , i was curious about what caused apache's ram spikes

Answer (score 0):

Not going to conjecture as to what's happening with the ram - the video doesn't show anything meaningful.

Since you're working with single instances of the script, use a profiling tool or instrument your code to find out what's happening.

Also, why are you explicitly extracting each value from the array? Why are you using such a dangerous method for doing it? (think about what happens if $array has a key 'array').

Go read the documentation and discussion for the [extract function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Comment: thanks , i have tried the same with extract function but the problem still persists .